# LINQ query left joining two tables with concatenation

Tags: linq

I am using this as a reference -- [how concatenate multiple rows in LINQ with two tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043915/how-concatenate-multiple-rows-in-linq-with-two-tables)

I have the exact same needs, except that not all "printers" have "resolutions". In my particular case, I have a Lead table, which stores some basic information. Then there is a tag table, which stores tags used for the Lead. Not every lead has a tag.

This is what I have so far based on the above reference:

```
        var leads = _dbRO.Leads.Join(_dbRO.Tags, p => p.LeadId, r => r.EntityId, (p, r) => new
        {
            LeadId = p.LeadId,
            GigDate = p.GigDate,
            Location = p.Location,
            Tags = String.Join("|", _dbRO.Tags.Where(k => k.EntityId == p.LeadId)
            .Select(lm => lm.TagName.ToString()))
        }).Distinct();
```

This works well for me. However, leads without tags are NOT returned. How do I ensure all leads are returned regardless of tags. An empty string or null for Tags field would be fine.

Also if you don't mind, if I want to return the Tags in an object array, how do I do that? The reason is because there could be additional information associated with each tag, like color etc. So a simple concatenated string might not be sufficient.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out -- I do not need to join the tag table at all. This causes the problem. I just need to select from my Lead table and in the Select section, get the tags as I was already doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve declared a relationship between Lead and Tag entity types, then EF already supplies your requirements through the Include() extension method.

```
ctx.Leads.Include(l => l.Tags).ToList()
```

This requires that Lead declares a navigation property to Tag as shown below.

```
class Lead
{ ... public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; } }
```

Comment: Actually no. There are no relations between the table. The Tag table is shared by multiple entities. That's why you see when referencing the Tag table, there is an EntityId.